# is there a way to do something like if (Variable == 1 or Variable == 2 or Variable == 3) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm somewhat new to javascript and I couldn't find anything with google search, I'm writing a program for something and being able to do something like what I've asked:  `if (Variable == 1 or Variable == 2 or Variable == 3)` would be a much cleaner and simpler solution to what I'm trying to do in it.

Comment: `v==1 || v==2 || v== 3`  ?

Comment: Just have `if (Variable == 1 || Variable == 2 || Variable == 3)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: Conditional statements are easy to find the syntax for in just about every popular language. I don't think this question is useful for the site.

Comment: whoah that was fast, thanks for the help, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if(variable==1||variable==2||variable==3){
  //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically its depend on requirment.
you can write this in some other more clear ways like

```
if ((Variable == 1 && Variable == 2) || Variable == 3)
```

if first 2 condition must be true an third one is OR

```
if (Variable == 1 && (Variable == 2 || Variable == 3))
```

if first condition must be true and second or third in one is true

Comment: i just didn't know about the || operator, thanks for the help, it's definitely much better then righting a huge if statment

Answer (score 0):

The comments to your question make good points, but in case you have to test your variable within a large set of values, something like this will be better.

```js
// Define an array of accepted values;

var acceptedValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// Test the variable.

var variable = 11;

if (acceptedValues.includes(variable))
    console.log("variable has a valid value");
else
   console.log("variable does not have a valid value");
```

Comment: However https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes - why not use indexOf which works in more browsers?

Comment: because why use old worst stuff when you can transpile?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a statement like this to determine, for example, if a mob in a video game should attack, who it should attack and what ELSE it could do if it does not attack.

```
if var 1 = 1 do (if var 2 = 2 do (if var 3 = 3 do (if var 1 < X (if var 2 < Y (if var 3 < Z do () else do ()) else do ()) else do ()) else do ()) else do ()) else do ()
```

This strig works pretty universally. It will work in visual basic, javascript, batch script and c#, assuming you can translate the (set /a var=1+1) variable of the various programing languages.

the pipepipe `||` statment is not necessarily an OR statment nor is it an `AND &&` statement, it is more like `if` (leftside) fails "||" `do` (`rightside`)

to arrange it differently

```
if var 1 = 1 do (
    if var 2 = 2 do (
        if var 3 = 3 do (
            if var 1 < X (
                if var 2 < Y (
                    if var 3 < Z do (
                    ) else do ()
                ) else do ()
            ) else do ()
        ) else do ()
    ) else do ()
) else do ()
```

The parenthesis and the "DO" statements are not necessary operators, however they make it much easier to look at and keep track of as well as help your notepad's highlighter keep track of long string components.